# What type of computer network would the Matrix be considered

Tags: the-matrix, computers

My basic understanding of computer networks is that they fall under two categories:

- [Client-Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server)

or

- [Peer to Peer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer)

Can the Matrix be defined in one of these two ways, or is there another category that it would best be in?

Comment: Are you asking about the underlying hardware which the Matrix runs on, or how the humans are connected to the Matrix?

Comment: More so how the humans are connected to the Matrix as well as each other @Xantec

Comment: One characterizes distributed applications or actually communication patterns as such, not computer networks.

Comment: We could reopen this. I *must disagree* with Kalissar. *Everyone* is able to manipulate the Matrix. Trinity can jump to the next building, not-rescued ('bluepill') athlete Dan Davis in World Record can use telekinesis. The users *cannot get localized* even in-matrix, that's why Morpheus wasn't yet caught at the beginning of the movies and they need to implant a bug into the protagonist.

Comment: Well a client can always somehow _hack_ the server, can't it ?

Comment: It's more than that. There are *places* inside the Matrix that *go unnoticed*, even if the machines oppose their existence. Some are *undesired*, but are left alone. Why? The 'official' system is at war with the exiles - yet the Merovingian can happily reside in his skyscraper-castle combination *and the system can do nothing but send Agents - at most*. So if your henchmen can protect a building, *the system cannot erase it*. In the Matrix, if you need to erase a virtual building, you do it **inside** the simulation or introduce dejavu. The Matrix **is far from being a simple client-server**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Matrix is *Client-Server* based : one's brain is a client, and the server *is* actually The Matrix**

Why ? Because there is an established world (the matrix), and this world is persistent, which means if you disconnect from it, it still runs for everybody else.

It would be peer-to-peer if everybody ran a small portion of the world, which means small parts of the world would disappear each time someone disconnect and reappear when the person reconnect.

But the person's data is stored in the brain... at least kind of. Think of it as an [MMORPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massively_multiplayer_online_role-playing_game) (Massively Multiplayer Online Role Playing Game). When Neo gets in the blank space to train or to get weapons, he kind of connects to another server run by the Nebuchadnezzar, save his data, and then connects to The Matrix with the new data/weapon.

Neo is The One because he can actually manipulate the Server.

Comment: If we forget for one moment the ridiculous humans as batteries thing and consider the original explanation of the machines using brains as additional processing power, then we are talking more peer-to-peer.

Comment: Actually i forgot that part. It would then be a _distributed_ processing, not really peer-to-peer. The difference is that in a peer-to-peer process, each peer is equal in the process, whereas in a distributed one, there usually is one "master" (which can be _elected_) which coordinates the computing. The master would here be the Matrix

Comment: I must disagree with this. I have more reasons but see my comment on Q.